# How to make laptop only start charging when under 20% while always plugged in?

Tags: laptop, battery, power-consumption

I want my laptop only to charge when under X% of battery is left, while always plugged-in to charger.

I have a laptop that has to be up in running for long periods and I want to lower the electricity consumption as much as possible. Since it is always plugged-in it is always charging.

Also, is this logical, or consumption will still be the same?

Thanks.

Comment: What brand of laptop?  For instance, Lenovo has an app for theirs that allows this behavior.

Comment: HP G62, this is an old laptop... but will do fine for home server :0

Comment: You're doing the right thing for the wrong reason.  You will prolong the battery's service life a little with this practice (although you risk running out of juice when you need it).  You won't save electricity because there is negligible charging current when the battery is full.

Comment: hmm maybe youre right. Any other tips on how to save on consumption?

Comment: Charging is controlled by the bios, no way to change its behavior.

Comment: Toshiba has a utility to limit charge to 80%, which is supposed to enhance the lifetime of the battery.